# How to specify custom date range in google adwords selector properly with python?

Tags: python, date, range, selector, google-ads-api

**My goal** is to get `ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT` with **custom date** range.

I've tried

```
oauth2_client = GoogleRefreshTokenClient(self.client_id, self.client_secret, refresh_token)
adwords_client = AdWordsClient(developer_token, oauth2_client, self.user_agent)
report_downloader = client.GetReportDownloader(version='v201809')
report={
  'reportName': 'Google xxx ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT', 
  'dateRangeType': 'CUSTOM_DATE', 
  'reportType': 'ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT', 
  'downloadFormat': 'CSV', 
  'selector': 
  {
     'fields': ['CustomerDescriptiveName', 'Date', 'Cost'], 
     'dateRange': '20200501,20201031'
  }
}
```

And got

```
Request Summary: 
{
'clientCustomerId': 'None', 
'includeZeroImpressions': 'True', 
'server': 'adwords.google.com', 
'skipColumnHeader': 'False', 
'skipReportHeader': 'False', 
'skipReportSummary': 'False', 
'isError': True, 
'errorMessage': '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><reportDownload
Error><ApiError><type>ReportDownloadError.INVALID_REPORT_DEFINITION_XML</type><trigger>Invalid ReportDefinition Xml: DateError.INVALID_STRING_DATE @ </t
rigger><fieldPath></fieldPath></ApiError></reportDownloadError>'
}
```

but when i use

```
report=
{
  'reportName': 'Google xxx ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT', 
  'dateRangeType': 'LAST_7_DAYS', 
  'reportType': 'ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT', 
  'downloadFormat': 'CSV', 
  'selector': 
  {
     'fields': ['CustomerDescriptiveName', 'Date', 'Cost']
  }
}
```

it's ok

The question is: ***How to specify custom `dateRange` range in `selector` properly?***

Answer (score 0):

While reading the documentation, I found the answer to my question. I've made a mistake when used awql syntax here.

The proper `dateRange` selector should have been:

```
'dateRange': {'min': '20200501', 'max': '20201031'}
```